# function parameter - Cannot find type of paramater

Tags: powershell

I am getting the following error when calling a PowerShell function:

```
Cannot find the type for custom attribute 'paramater'. 
Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
```

I have had this error before and it was spacing in the function that was causing the error, but it doesn't seem the be the same this time, I have had a look around and couldn't find a fix. Here is the function:

```
function fn_API-GetAll {
    param ( 
            [paramater(Mandatory=$true)]$API 
    )
    return (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $API)
}
```

and here is the call:

```
$coinMarketCap        = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
$coinMarketCap_Global = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/"

$fullAPI = fn_API-GetAll -API $coinMarketCap
$fullAPI
```

Comment: Looks like a simple typo..."parameter" is what you want.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I have read that small piece of code and missed that... Thanks, why is the paramater still highlighted light blue in ISE?

Comment: Perhaps because it's in square brackets it is treated as a type, whatever is written there.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Booga Roo in a comment, `Parameter` is not spelled `paramater`

Hope that helps